# Desktop empty after login Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gui

I really need someone's help. I don't know what else to do, I've read all forums trying all sort of manipulations without managing to solve my problem.

After my login my desktop is empty. I don't know exactly what happend, everything was working well but I think it was after an upate. I cannot access the terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> only with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>.

I'm running under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Virtual Box (Windows 8 host).

I've tried (among others) :

`unity --replace`

and I have the following error :

```
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded
```

I'm not an expert with Linux but I can do some basic stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything and still have the same problem check the `~/.xsession-errors` log file and see if there is an error like this:

```
init: dbus pre-start process (PID XXXX) terminated with status 2
```

If that's the case you may have a problem with the upstart cache. After `rm -rf ~/.cache/upstart` and a reboot unity started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by reinstalling Unity and rebooting:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity
sudo reboot -r now
```